# Spring Security error: no bean named "springSecurityFilterChain"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web, spring-security

I am working on a project where I seek to implement Spring Security, but I have an error since I put the filter and filter mapping in web.xml. I am currently following a tutorial where the person in the video follows the same steps as me and didnt get any error, but I do. So i am quite confused. Is there anyone that could help me a bit?[image]

I am also attaching my code.
This is what I put in web.xml:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
 
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And this is my SecurityConfiguration.java class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Checu").password("dummy")
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/", "/*todo*/**").access("hasRole('USER')").and()
                .formLogin();
    }
}
```

It's not much, but I'd like to make it work and when i call the localhost:8080/login to show to default login form.
Thanks in advance a bunch.

Comment: Could you provide the console output of the server start? Looks like the bean did not get loaded into the context.

Comment: It s quite extensive to be honest, i can't paste all here, the thing is I read something about using something like this : <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

Comment: but it s not working, it gives me another error